# Parole italiane con due categorie grammaticali

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, list

La parola *danza* in italiano può essere, a seconda del contesto, un sostantivo (*la danza*) oppure un verbo (*egli danza*). La parola *lingua*, invece, ha due significati (parte del corpo oppure linguaggio), ma sono entrambi sostantivi.

1. Esiste un nome per indicare le parole del primo tipo, ma non quelle del secondo?
2. Esiste una risorsa che fa un elenco di queste parole, per esempio ad uso degli enigmisti?

Answer (score 3):

È semplicemente un casuale processo di omonimia, e non mi risulta abbia altro nome. Diverso il caso della derivazione zero, in italiano poco diffuso (ad esempio la sostantivazione di verbi e aggettivi), mentre ben noto in inglese (Google > to google). Solo in quest'ultimo caso sarebbero effettivamente "parole con diverse categorie grammaticali"

Il punto cruciale della differenza è nel fatto che "egli danza" è alla terza persona, cioè non è alla prima persona dell'indicativo presente: vale a dire che si è formato per caso in seguito al banale meccanismo flessivo interno al verbo stesso, non come conversione da un'altra parte del discorso. Non c'è insomma un tentativo volontario di creare un collegamento tra le due parole.

Riguardo al trovarne una lista dovrai spulciare qualche lista di omonimi abbastanza ben curata da includere anche corrispondenze con parole non nella forma di dizionario (egli danza).

Quanto a "lingua", è invece un caso di polisemia. Polisemia e omonimia sono entrambi casi di omografia, ma opposti: nei primi c'è un legame etimologico/semantico trai vari significati, nel secondo no. Dovrai cercare esplicitamente una lista di omonimi, non di omografi; in questo modo sarai ragionevolmente sicuro di non incorrere in parole polisemiche.

Comment: Si però nella polisemia, le due parole hanno significati diversi, ma la stessa etimologia. Mentre nell'omonimia l'uguaglianza è casuale.

Nel caso di "lingua" penso si tratti di polisemia, mentre per esempio "radio" è un'omonimia.

Comment: Ho precisato la domanda; mi interessa in particolare un nome che descrive parole con due significati appartenenti a categorie grammaticali diverse.

Comment: @WalterVilla certo!

Comment: @FedericoPoloni quello che chiedi non ha senso, intendo dire che omonimia e polisemia sono due cose diverse, opposte anzi: quindi le liste di omonimi non includono mai i casi di polisemia

Comment: In che senso "quello che chiedi non ha senso"? Mi sembra una domanda perfettamente valida: ho descritto una categoria di parole, facendo anche degli esempi per chiarire meglio, e chiedo se essa ha un nome.

Comment: Non ha senso chiedere una lista di omonimi che non includa parole polisemiche (l'edit che hai fatto, non la domanda intera), in quanto essendo cose diverse non troverai liste che le contengano entrambe (se non cerchi "omografi" ma "omonimi", in caso contrario saranno presenti entrambe)

Comment: Chiedo anch'io: che vuol dire “non ha senso”? Magari a te non interessa, ma è un insieme (ragionevolmente) ben definito: tutte le stringhe di lettere che in italiano hanno più di una categoria grammaticale, indipendentemente se ci sia contiguità etimologica (“danza”) o no (“sette”). Ha interesse, quanto meno, per l'enigmistica come dice FP e persino per l'intelligenza artificiale e la traduzione automatica (“la vecchia porta la sbarra” è un classico esempio di simili ambiguità raccolte insieme, di difficile interpretazione per un programma di IA).

Comment: Poi, certo, la lista sarebbe immensa, ma magari un programma ad hoc, che parta da un corpus ben strutturato, la potrebbe generare facilmente.

Comment: @Dag Certo, mi ero spiegato male: intendevo dire che non aveva senso la distinzione introdotta nell'edit (", ma non quelle del secondo"), non l'intera domanda, che anzi è interessante

Comment: @DaG purtroppo non è così facile generare automaticamente la lista. Avresti bisogno di un software abbastanza intelligente da capire il significato della parola. Specialmente il tuo esempio della vecchia potrebbe essere disambiguato solo ed esclusivamente su base probabilistica, e a patto di possedere un corpus immenso.

Comment: @DaG per vedere cosa è possibile fare attualmente puoi leggere il manuale della libreria per il [natural language processing](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html) in python, una delle migliori. Molto poco purtroppo.

Comment: Non c'è bisogno di capire il significato: bastano le categorie grammaticali, appunto (per questo parlavo di “corpus ben strutturato”). Penso a una base di dati, o dizionario, del tipo “danza, n; danzare, v; ...; setta, n; sette, a” e a un programma che sappia flettere (o consultarne la flessione) le parti del discorso non invarianti. È una noia, ma i computer sanno fare bene proprio le cose noiose.

Comment: @DaG è vero! ero fissato scioccamente sul fatto che dovesse avere un corpus di testi, ma a lui serve un corpus di *vocaboli*. In questo caso è davvero molto facile scrivere un programma di tal genere. L'unico problema sono le forme flesse irregolari, che devono essere indicate a mano prima di lanciare il programma.